# How do I build MySQL server (5.5.8 is current latest)

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade MySQL to 5.5, am I best off waiting for it to be available through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-upgrade-mysql-to-5-5-am-i-best-off-waiting-for-it-to-be-available-throu)

How do i build MySql server? i was hoping for `./configure;make;make install` but it doesnt seem to be that easy. Basically i want the default settings (as you would get on the distro or even in windows) and doing this to get a newer version (5.0 to 5.5).

Comment: posible duplicate see that -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-upgrade-mysql-to-5-5-am-i-best-off-waiting-for-it-to-be-available-throu/18049#18049

Answer (score 0):

To install:

Remember that the instructions in the MySQL manual assume you are logged in as 'root'. See RootSudo.

Another thing I ran into - before running the 'scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql' command you must have installed libaio1.

I just removed and installed manually using MySQL docs. I am running the 'perl mysql-test-run.pl' now. Been running successfully for 25 minutes but thought you'd like preliminary answer(s).

Cheers.

Comment: When i run `sudo scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql` i get `101230 21:07:42 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql/english/..'`

Comment: When using 'root' you shouldn't need 'sudo'. In terminal, use 'sudo -i' to to simulate a Root login shell then run the scripts. Worked for me...

Comment: I haven't removed it (i was afraid of breaking it) but what docs are you talking about? docs/mysql.info doesnt look like an installation guide (I was using `less` so maybe i didnt scroll far enough to see it).