# PPA for MySQL 5.5 underway?

Tags: ppa, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade MySQL to 5.5, am I best off waiting for it to be available through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-upgrade-mysql-to-5-5-am-i-best-off-waiting-for-it-to-be-available-throu)

Are there any efforts in this direction? PostgreSQL 9.0 is already available via PPA, what about MySQL? Would be rather interesting.