# How to fetch the latest version of MySQL using tools like APT?

Tags: mysql, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade MySQL to 5.5, am I best off waiting for it to be available through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-upgrade-mysql-to-5-5-am-i-best-off-waiting-for-it-to-be-available-thro)

This fetches revision 5.1 only:

```
  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but the latest community server version is 5.5.9

Comment: please look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76919/upgrade-to-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Answer (score 5):

apt-get is a tool specific to debian-based linux distributions, and will only download packages from locations specified in /etc/apt/source.lst.

To update to 5.5, you will either need to find a repository with the newer builds and add it to your sources.lst, or you'll have to manually download and install one of the packages from mysql's site.

Comment: @Andee - Any ideas on what that repository would be for mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can download RPM package from MySQL download page and convert it using alien. Then you can install .deb package using "dpkg -i". Download RPM package (64bit or 32bit), and run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install alien fakeroot
fakeroot alien MySQL-devel-5.5.9-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm
dpkg -i mysql-devel_5.5.9-2_i386.deb
```

That is better than installing from source code, as now files are tracked by dpkg (backend for apt, aptitude and other package managers in Ubuntu).

There is no [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) offering newest mysql-server for Ubuntu, at least I couldn't find it. 5.1 is considered as stable mysql, while 5.5 is "upstream version". There will be Ubuntu packages, but good question is when.