# Upgrade to mySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade MySQL to 5.5, am I best off waiting for it to be available through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-upgrade-mysql-to-5-5-am-i-best-off-waiting-for-it-to-be-available-thro)

I've seen that mySQL 5.5 has a lot of innoDB performance enhancements.

Is there an easy way to upgrade mySQL 5.1 to 5.5 on Natty?

Comment: If there is no new information about this in 11 months, then I guess it is a duplicate.