# Installing MySQL-server-5.5.15-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm

Tags: installation, rpm

I downloaded `MySQL-server-5.5.15-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm` from mysql.com. But I don't know how to install it.

Comment: Why don't you install mysql-server from the repos?

Comment: There is a similar question a about upgrade. The instruction  may help you in fresh installation too. http://askubuntu.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-upgrade-mysql-to-5-5-am-i-best-off-waiting-for-it-to-be-available-throu

Comment: fyi: rpm is for redhat. you are better of with a .deb to install it under Ubuntu (and you can use ubuntu software center for that).

Answer (score 2):

If you want 5.5 you need to download the `tar.gz` version and not the `rpm` from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html and follow the instructions from this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-installation.html 
Relevant portions from this instruction (but do read the link itself too):

2.2. Installing MySQL from Generic Binaries on Unix/Linux
Oracle provides a set of binary distributions of MySQL. These include binary distributions in the form of compressed tar files (files with a .tar.gz extension) for a number of platforms, as well as binaries in platform-specific package formats for selected platforms.

<..>

This section covers the installation of MySQL from a compressed tar file binary distribution. For other platform-specific package formats, see the other platform-specific sections. 
To install and use a MySQL binary distribution, the basic command sequence looks like this:

```
shell> groupadd mysql
shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql
shell> cd /usr/local
shell> tar zxvf /path/to/mysql-VERSION-OS.tar.gz
shell> ln -s full-path-to-mysql-VERSION-OS mysql
shell> cd mysql
shell> chown -R mysql .
shell> chgrp -R mysql .
shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
shell> chown -R root .
shell> chown -R mysql data
# Next command is optional
shell> cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
# Next command is optional
shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

A more detailed version of the preceding description for installing a binary distribution can be found at the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the .rpm to a .deb file for it to work with Ubuntu. You can do this using [alien](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/alien). Then install the .deb file with `dpkg -i`.

It is much easier to just use the repositories, or download the .deb files from the site ( if there are any).