# Is it possible / avaliable to Upgrade to MySQl 5.5

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade MySQL to 5.5, am I best off waiting for it to be available through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18023/how-do-i-upgrade-mysql-to-5-5-am-i-best-off-waiting-for-it-to-be-available-thro)

Upgrade to MySQL version 5.5? If so. It is not in the synaptics package manger.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you'll have to compile it from source: [MySQL Download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

You eventually can convert an RPM package to a deb package (there's a tool named "alien" for that), but you don't want to do that.